# CXF validating the wsdl before calling service

Tags: cxf

We are using CXF2.5.2 in PROD, our wsdl url can go down anytime ,So  while calling cxf service ,as it validates wsdl from the url ,it fails if the wsdl url is offline.

Is there any way ,can it be switched off to validate wsdl url while calling the service other than keeping wsdl in local .